# Extend JetBrains Product Pack for Students license

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I registered for student's license for all JetBrains products some time ago using my email on *.edu.* domain. Soon the license will expire, so my question is, will I be able to register again for next license using same email? Or is there any way for me to further extend existing license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms of a particular program/service. // And getting in touch which JetBrains directly and ask them would probably be the smart(est) option here.

Comment: I completely agree, I wrote this question compulsively without doing sufficient research. I would close/delete it myself since I already found the answer. But I can as well post it now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an answer in JetBrains Student License FAQ:

> (..) After one year you will need to renew your Student License for the next year, or purchase a license if you’re no longer a student.

Also:

> If you’re still a student, feel free to renew the Student License for another year. To do so, use the dedicated link in your JetBrains account, or check the email reminder we send out one week before your license expires for the same link.

https://www.jetbrains.com/student/#faq

Comment: How do they verify if you are still a student or not?

Comment: When you register for students licence you have to provide either email with .edu domain or students identity card. Emails with .edu domain are usually valid only through academic activity periods and the latter have "valid through" dates. So when your licence expires (after one year) you can't just keep registering forever. I think.

Comment: can't find so called "dedicated link in your JetBrains account" did you find it?